# Why does null <> "something" return false

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I was debugging a procedure in an oracle database when I came across something that surprised me regarding NULL values. Can anybody explain why the following query returns false for the non equality check here?

```
DECLARE
    vNullVariable VARCHAR2(2) := NULL;
    vVariable VARCHAR2(2) := 'Hi';
BEGIN
    IF vNullVariable <> vVariable THEN
        dbms_output.put_line( 'The variables are not equal' );
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line( 'The variables are equal' );
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because SQL uses three-valued logic (3VL): there is **TRUE**, there is **FALSE** and there is **NULL** (unknown, neither TRUE nor FALSE).

The result of the expression `vNullVariable <> vVariable` is NULL, not TRUE, in 3VL because it considers the value of vNullVariable to be unknown: if at a later time it becomes a known value, it might be 'Hi' or it might not, but right now SQL doesn't know so it returns NULL (unknown).

So the IF expression evaluates to NULL, not TRUE, and so the default ELSE path is taken instead - because the logic if IF is:

```
IF <expression is true> THEN
   ...
ELSE -- ie. if expression is FALSE or NULL
   ...
END IF;
```

This means that you **would** get the behaviour you were expecting if you wrote the check the other way around:

```
IF vNullVariable = vVariable THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'The variables are equal' );
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line( 'The variables are not equal' );
END IF;
```

Comment: Are there standard ways of working with this? I don't always expect the value to be NULL, but either way I would like the code in the IF block to execute.
The only thing I can think of is adding something like (vNullVariable IS NULL AND vVariable IS NOT NULL) AND (.reverse.) AND ( <> ).

Comment: You can do that, or do the = check instead of the <> check as in my update.

Comment: Sometimes people use nvl: `if nvl(v1,'XXX') <> nvl(v2.'XXX') then...`.  The trouble is of course you need to use defaults that couldn't actually be a real non-null value!

Comment: +1 for mention that `NULL` is unknown so we can't say that it is not equal to 'Hi'

Comment: when using the = check, please keep in mind, that the result will be false, if both variables are NULL.

Comment: @Juergen: well the result will be NULL not FALSE, but you have a point - it will fall into the ELSE which may not be what the user expects.  In which case we have to start using `if (a is null and b is null) or a = b then...`

Answer (score 2):

NULL's has strange behaviour on Oracle. To compare something with null, is better to use IS NULL instead of '=NULL'

[Here](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com.es/2005/06/nulls-in-oracle.html)  you have a good explanation about

In your code, you can use

```
IF vVariable IS NOT NULL THEN
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, NULL is neither equal to nor not equal to NULL. A comparison condition that evaluates two NULLs will always be FALSE. The following conditions involving NULL will be valid.

```
1. IF vNullVariable is NULL THEN
2. IF vNullVariable is not NULL THEN
3. IF NVL(vNullVariable, -1) <> NVL(vVariable, -1) THEN -
    This condition will give you expected result even if both vNullVariabl 
    and vVariable are NULLs
4. Oracle considers two nulls to be equal when evaluating a DECODE function
```

for example the following query will give you 1 if first and second arguments of `DECODE` function are `NULLs`

```
    select decode(null, null, 1) res
      from dual;

 res
-------
  1
```